# Shell: Checking if argument exists and matches expression

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm new to shell scripting and trying to write the ability to check if an argument exists and if it matches an expression. I'm not sure how to write expressions, so this is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -n "$1"] && [${1#*.} -eq "tar.gz"]]; then
  echo "Passed";
else 
  echo "Missing valid argument"
fi
```

To run the script, I would type this command:

```
# script.sh YYYY-MM.tar.gz
```

I believe what I have is

1. if the YYYY-MM.tar.gz is not after script.sh it will echo "Missing valid argument" and
2. if the file does not end in .tar.gz it echo's the same error.

However, I want to also check if the full file name is in YYYY-MM.tar.gz format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if [[ -n "$1" ]] && [[ "${1#*.}" == "tar.gz" ]]; then
```

`-eq`: (equal) for arithmetic tests

`==`: to compare strings

See: `help test`

Comment: Thanks!  Adding a second pair of [] helped fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
case "$1" in
        *.tar.gz) ;; #passed
        *) echo "wrong/missing argument $1"; exit 1;;
esac
echo "ok arg: $1"
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the file is in the correct `YYYY-MM.tar.gz` format, it obviously is non-empty and ends in `.tar.gz` as well. Check with a regular expression:

```
if ! [[ $1 =~ [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}.tar.gz ]]; then
    echo "Argument 1 not in correct YYYY-MM.tar.gz format"
    exit 1
fi
```

Obviously, the regular expression above is too general, allowing names like 0193-67.tar.gz. You can adjust it to be as specific as you need it to be for your application, though. I might recommend

```
[1-9][0-9]{3}-([1-9]|10|11|12).tar.gz
```

to allow only 4-digit years starting with 1000 (support for the first millennium ACE seems unnecessary) and only months 1-12 (no leading zero).

Comment: You can up-vote as many answers as you like; you just can accept only one as the one you found most helpful.